# How to get list of workspace variables accessed by a Matlab script (*.m) file?

Tags: matlab, variables, workspace

Is there a code-analyzing function/utility that gives a list of existing workspace variables **used/accessed by a .m script file**?

Scenario:
Three scripts run in sequence. The first one makes a bunch of variables. The second uses a subset of the variables made by the first. The third uses a subset of variables made by first and second scripts. 
I want a list of vars **accessed** by the second and third scripts. I do not want a complete list of vars given by who().

Comment: @TroyHaskin I don't think it's a duplicate. OP also wants to get variables that were accessed (read). This is difficult, even when you don't consider evil `eval`. Using `load`, a script can load arbitrary variables into a workspace, and likewise, with `save` and a variable argument arbitrary variables can be read. Heck, even the MATLAB editor isn't very good at detecting access of undefined variables ...

Comment: @TroyHaskin, zeeMonkeez is right.

Comment: Not that I have an answer, but: do you count `if exist('foo', 'var'); bar=foo; end` as accessing `foo` or not?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I deleted the comments.  What's the end goal of this functionality?

Comment: that's a horrible way to code, use proper functions with inputs and outputs, instead of relying on dependent scripts like that! Anyway there might be some submissions on FEX that can help here: fdep, farg, ..

Comment: @TroyHaskin I use the file-system (*.mat) to send/receive stuff between Matlab and Julia. The calculations make huge matrices in the workspace. If I have a list of vars used at each step, I can 'clear' the unneeded stuff. I believe, this would aid in better use of storage space as the experimental data grows.

Comment: @Amro I still have to investigate the penalty, if any, of passing/returning huge matrices to/from functions. Matrix sizes are 60,000x60,000 or above.

Comment: there is no memory penalty in passing and returning matrices to/from functions! MATLAB uses lazy copy-on-write strategy, as long as a function input is not modified think of it as "pass by const ref" similar to C/C++.. In MATLAB when you write `A = zeros(..some big mat..); B=A` it will share data, a copy is only made when you make modifications. So there is no reason for you not to use functions!

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using both MATLAB and Julia? They are alike, just pick one and write all your code in it.. Even their syntax is quite similar, so it should be easy to port the code to one language..

Comment: @Amro, I agree nothing like the structure provided by functions. 1. It would take time to refactor the current (tested) code to use functions. Took me months to understand and code the math. 2. Having a tool that detects which vars are used by a which script would save time in manually figuring out function arguments.

Comment: @Amro I have part of the work in Julia coz of its way-better-support for parallel programming. Porting the code is not tough but took time.

Comment: MATLAB has [DEPFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/depfun.html) to list function [dependencies](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html), but that's not exactly what you want.. The only way I see is to parse the M-code with something like [farg](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15924-farg--a-pedestrian-m-file-parser-showing-all-used-functions--syntax) and extract from that variables used. I doubt this will be easy though! I've seen other solutions to parse M-code, google is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an easy way to do this, however I think I have thought of a way to do this it does assume your scripts are quick to run - otherwise it will take forever as it runs each script many times to find the dependencies.

**Before I go into the detail - a much better solution in the short and especially the long term is to convert your scripts to functions - its really not that hard I've done it with clients code a number of times).**

So how to do it with scripts...

To demonstrate I create 3 dummy scripts for testing

```
% SCRIPT 1 - a truly horrible way to create variables - NEVER do this in practice...
for ii=97:122
  eval ( sprintf ( '%s = %i;', char(ii), ii ) );
end
```

Script 2

```
% SCRIPT 2 - simply access some of the variables created above.
e;
a;
b;
c;
h;
t;
v;
```

Script 3

```
% SCRIPT 3 - a similar script which access vars (some shared with 2)
a;
b;
c;
e;
m;
n;
v;
z;
```

Now we create a method which will run your scripts a number of times removing each var at a time to check if its needed:

```
function testScript
  % run script 1 to get all variables
  script1;
  % save to a temp file
  save ( 'temp' );
  % run the function that does the work
  runner ( 'temp' )
end
function runner ( fname )
  % load the variables
  allvars = load(fname);
  % extract out all the variables
  fnames = fieldnames(allvars);
  % calculate the number of total variables
  nvars = length(fnames);
  % create a array to save whether the script runs or not
  flags = true(nvars,1);
  % loop through all variables - removing them 1 at a time from the 
  %  workspace to see if the dependent script runs without each variable
  for iCount=1:nvars
    % run the test
    flags(iCount) = runTestWithoutVar ( fname, fnames{iCount} );
  end
  % display the variables required to run the script.
  disp ( fnames(~flags) )
end
function flag = runTestWithoutVar ( fname, removeVar )
  % load the data
  load(fname)
  % remove one variable
  clear ( removeVar )
  try
    % try to run script2
    script2;
    % You can also run script3 -> that will produce a complete list
    %     script3;
    % return true is script runs okay.
    flag = true;
  catch
    % return false if it crashes (i.e. that variable was needed)
    flag = false;
  end
end
```

I re-iterate a couple of points:

1. If your scripts are slow this may be unpractical.
2. Converting to functions would be much better! :)

Comment: matlabgui, thank you for answering. In my work, the second script takes over 30 mins. I wonder if not using functions could be a programming anti-pattern :).

Comment: You could try and identify what takes time (your `profile`) and you may be able make a small modification to reduce the time just to asses the variable question...

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest another not very clear way.

1. Create a Simulink project (Home->New->Simulink project). Don't
   bother, we won't need any Simulink.
2. Add your script to the project.
3. Run dependency analysis.

For test I created an m-file **xz.m**:

```
z = a + 4 * b;
disp(z);
```

And here is the result. Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Zvord, The visual output is very appealing. I will definitely like to explore it as soon as I find time to play with Simulink for the first time. :)